# Populating dropdown with GET data from separate JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've inherited a project and the original author split their code into separate JS files. One of them contains all of the GET requests, such as Departments, Categories, Titles, etc.

I have some code for an autocomplete dropdown in a separate file, `index.js`, and **I want to populate the dropdown with the Department results.** I'm not that well-versed in JS and I'm not sure what I have to do to "connect" the files and reference the Departments GET request.

#### index.js:

```
import "jquery";
import "jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css";
import "jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js";

function loadCombobox() {
    let depts = {
        "t1": "1",
        "t2": "2"
    } // added this as a test

    let deptsArray = $.map(depts, function(value, key) {
        return {
            value: value,
            data: key
        };
    })
    console.log(deptsArray);

    $('#combobox').autocomplete({
        source: deptsArray
    }).on("click", function() {
        console.log("combobox clicked") // works
    });
}

loadCombobox();
```

#### data-request.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = siteAbsoluteUrl;
const deptList = "Department List";

async function makeGetRequest(url) {
  const response = await axios.get(url, getRequestConfig);
  const { results, __next } = response.data.d;
  return { results, __next };
}

// gives back an array containing all departments, without duplicates
export async function makeDepartmentsRequest() {
  const { results } = await makeGetRequest(
    `${baseUrl}/getbytitle('${deptBPList}')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Department'`
  );
  return results[0].Choices.results;
}
```

#### html:

```
<input type="text" id="combobox" placeholder="Browse departments">
```

#### console:

[image]

Comment: Import `makeDepartmentsRequest` in `index.js` like `import { makeDepartmentsRequest } from 'path-to/data-request'`

Comment: Thanks @Mohrn. So if I wanted to set the autocomplete's `source` to the Departments, would I do something like `source: makeDepartmentsRequest.results[0].Choices.results` ?

Comment: Not quite. a) `makeDepartmentsRequest` is a function so we have to call it. b) `makeDepartmentsRequest` is an asynchronous function so we must wait for it (with `await` or `then`)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the end result (note that I don't know what `makeDepartmentsRequest` returns or what `#combobox` is so I can't test this code)

```js
import { makeDepartmentsRequest } from "path-to/data-request";

function loadCombobox() {
  makeDepartmentsRequest.then(choices => {
    const source = $.map(depts, function(value, key) {
      return {
        value: value,
        data: key
      };
    });
    $("#combobox")
      .autocomplete({
        source
      })
      .on("click", function() {
        console.log("combobox clicked"); // works
      });
  });
}
```